# How to call a group of functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I don't know how to do it so that the result label should displays the new result every time the button is pressed, should I copy and paste the 3 rock, paper and scissors functions in the repeat function or what?

its python 2.7

```
from Tkinter import*
import random
# variables
a = "rock"
b = "paper"
c = "scissors"
pc = random.choice([a, b, c])
windows = Tk()
windows.geometry("200x300")


# function that makes the

def repeat():
    pc = random.choice([a, b, c])
    print pc
    # im stuck here!





def tie():
    lbresult.configure(text="Tie!")



def win():
    lbresult.configure(text="you win!!")



def loose():
    lbresult.configure(text="you loose")



# functions for each election
def rock():
    if pc == "paper":
        loose()
    elif pc == "rock":
        tie()
    elif pc == "scissors":
        win()
    repeat()


def paper():
    if pc == "paper":
        tie()
    elif pc == "rock":
        win()
    elif pc == "scissors":
        loose()
    repeat()


def scissors():
    if pc == "paper":
        win()
    elif pc == "rock":
        loose()
    elif pc == "scissor":
        tie()
    repeat()


#buttons for choosing options
lbresult = Label(text="result will appear here")
btrock = Button(text="  rock    ", command=rock)
btpaper = Button(text="  paper  ", command=paper)
btscissors = Button(text="scissors", command=scissors)

btrock.pack()
btpaper.pack()
btscissors.pack()
lbresult.pack()
#result label


windows.mainloop()
```

please help im getting crazy trying to solve this,

if you can answer, please explain me why... I'll appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn what a local variable is. The simplest (even though stupid) solution is to use the `global` keyword, like so:

```
def repeat():
    global pc
    pc = random.choice([a, b, c])
    print(pc)
```

But never use `global` if the code should be reliable or developable. Here is the solution without it, learn OOP to understand:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class RPS:
    def __init__(self):
        self.windows = Tk()
        self.windows.geometry("200x300")

        self.a = "rock"
        self.b = "paper"
        self.c = "scissors"
        self.repeat()

        self.lbresult = Label(text="result will appear here")
        btrock = Button(text="  rock    ", command=self.rock)
        btpaper = Button(text="  paper  ", command=self.paper)
        btscissors = Button(text="scissors", command=self.scissors)

        btrock.pack()
        btpaper.pack()
        btscissors.pack()
        self.lbresult.pack()

        self.windows.mainloop()
    def repeat(self):
        self.pc = random.choice([self.a, self.b, self.c])
        print(self.pc)
    def tie(self):
        self.lbresult.configure(text="Tie!")
    def win(self):
        self.lbresult.configure(text="you win!!")
    def loose(self):
        self.lbresult.configure(text="you loose")
    def rock(self):
        if self.pc == "paper":
            self.loose()
        elif self.pc == "rock":
            self.tie()
        elif self.pc == "scissors":
            self.win()
        self.repeat()
    def paper(self):
        if self.pc == "paper":
            self.tie()
        elif self.pc == "rock":
            self.win()
        elif self.pc == "scissors":
            self.loose()
        self.repeat()
    def scissors(self):
        if self.pc == "paper":
            self.win()
        elif self.pc == "rock":
            self.loose()
        elif self.pc == "scissor":
            self.tie()
        self.repeat()
RPS()
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Pick a new random `pc` choice when and only when a button is pressed.

```
...
c = "scissors"
pc = random.choice([a, b, c]) # remove this
windows = Tk()
...

...
def rock():
    pc = random.choice([a, b, c])
    if pc == "paper":
        loose()
    elif pc == "rock":
        tie()
    elif pc == "scissors":
        win()
    repeat() # remove this, and the whole repeat function itself
...
```

Note that if you're just going to show the final result of win/loss/tie, the game itself doesn't actually need any logic. Just have all three buttons connect to the same function which shows that result:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
windows = Tk()
windows.geometry("200x300")

def play():
    lbresult.configure(text=random.choice(['You win!', 'You lose!', 'Tie!']))

lbresult = Label(text="result will appear here")
btrock = Button(text="  rock    ", command=play)
btscissors = Button(text="scissors", command=play)
btpaper = Button(text="  paper  ", command=play)

btrock.pack()
btpaper.pack()
btscissors.pack()
lbresult.pack()
#result label

windows.mainloop()
```

Also note that Python 2 is now officially unsupported and is no longer receiving any updates, including security patches. Anyone learning Python today should be learning Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible approaches here. The one that would most closely resemble your current approach would be by passing a function. You have a function, like this:

```
paper()
```

Functions can have arguments. Those arguments would go into the parentheses, and they become variables within that function. Just as a example, you could have one function, play(), and pass 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors' to it like this:

```
def play(user_choice):
  if user_choice == 'paper':
    paper()
  if user_choice == 'rock':
    rock()
....
```

You would then call that function like this:

```
>>> play('paper')
```

In that example, I'm passing the string 'paper' to the function play(). However, I can pass the function play() to a function as well, like this:

```
def play(func):
  func()
```

By this method, I can send the function "rock" "paper" or "scissors" to the function play, and then call whatever function I passed. You could - though it's probably not the best approach - pass a function to another function within itself:

```
def repeat(func):
  func()

def play():
  # do your things
  repeat(play)
```

But.. that approach is redundant. No sense in creating a function just to call a function, when you can instead simply call the function:

```
def play():
  # do your things
  play()
```

This is a recursive function. At the end of the function, it calls itself again. This will go on forever if you don't stop it, so the recursion would usually be written conditionally:

```
def play():
  # do your things
  continue = input("Would you like to continue [y/n]? ")
  if continue == 'y':
    play()
  else:
    pass    
    # This else statement is implicit. If you don't add it, it'll do it anyway.
```

Another option is a loop, like a 'while loop':

```
def play():
  keep_going = True
  while keep_going:
    #do your things
    continue = input("Would you like to continue [y/n]? ")
    if continue == "y":
      keep_going = True
    else:
      keep_going = False
```

A while loop is like a recursive if statement. When the code gets to the while statement, it determines whether the statement is true or false, only running the code within if it's true. Unlike an if statement, though, when it's done running the code, it will go back and reevaluate the statement again, and if it's still true, run it again. A while loop will only end if you're changing the variables that it evaluates such that the statement will eventually evaluate to false, at which point the program continues.